# How to add a dictionary as the last element to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I would like to add a dictionary to a list, which contains several other dictionaries.

1. I have a list of ten top travel cities:

   ```
                City      Country  Population     Area

   0         Buenos Aires    Argentina     2891000     4758
   1              Toronto       Canada     2800000  2731571

   2          Pyeongchang  South Korea     2581000     3194

   3             Marakesh      Morocco      928850      200

   4          Albuquerque   New Mexico      559277      491

   5            Los Cabos       Mexico      287651     3750

   6           Greenville          USA       84554       68

   7      Archipelago Sea      Finland       60000     8300

   8   Walla Walla Valley          USA       32237       33

   9        Salina Island        Italy        4000       27

   10               Solta      Croatia        1700       59

   11        Iguazu Falls    Argentina           0      672
   ```
2. I imported the excel with pandas:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   travel_df = pd.read_excel('./cities.xlsx')
   print(travel_df)
   cities = travel_df.to_dict('records')
   print(cities)
   variables = list(cities[0].keys())
   ```
3. I would like to add a 12th element to the end of the list but don't know how to do so:

   ```
   beijing = {"City" : "Beijing", "Country" : "China", "Population" : "24000000", "Ares" : "6490" }
   print(beijing)
   ```

Comment: You dont have any `list`s. Do you want to add a new row to the dataframe? Or do you just want an element to the `dict` you get in 3?

Comment: Title should be *How to add a dictionary at the end of a pandas dataframe?*.

Answer (score 4):

Try appending the new row to the DataFrame you read.

```
travel_df.append(beijing, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't the op want to append to cities or variables instead of travel_df?